# how to make page stop when click other tab in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Let's say I have multiple tabs in chrome and current tab is on Youtube. In chrome, If I click
another tab, the Youtube still works so I can hear the sound. I want to make the Youtube stops
when I click other tab. I mean not destoying the Youtube but stop the page. whenever I come back to Youtube tab, so I can keep run the video.

It is like applications when we use our smart phones. when we click the home button, current application stops and we can reopen our application whenever we want. I wonder how can I approach this in electron.

Comment: How are you doing tabs right now? Are you using `electron-tabs`? Or do you have two separate windows, each representing a tab?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your interest. Can you check my new writing about this question? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191539/how-to-make-mobile-like-electron-application-i-attached-images

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.