# How to make mobile-like electron application (I attached images)

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOkB0.png)

I am trying to make this electron application. This application act like cell phone. The picture above is the main.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uICel.png)

When I click the Youtube app, It opens Youtube page with Webview or BrowserView whatever. Let’s say I played a video.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Ce4.png)

When I click the Home button, It goes to the main. The thing is the video should be stopped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwYi5.png)

Additionally, If I click the Youtube app in the main page, previous page should be loaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN3us.png)

What I am thinking is to make two BrowserView that is view1 and view2 using ipcRenderer. but I have totally no idea **how to save the state of page and restore it** like I mentioned above. I need your help folks.

Comment: This is going to be tricky, with no straightfoward answer. I'd suggest seeing if [`electron-tabs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-tabs) works for you. If not then take a look at [this page](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/web-embeds) on how to embed websites into Electron, out of them all I think `BrowserView` will work the best for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.